# Will a Default Constructor With no Parameters Always Initialize Variables?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a class that contains a default constructor that is supposed initialize several private member variables. I am wondering if my variables are ever initialized because when I call the variables_in_class method nothing is printed. Could someone explain this to me? My code is below:

```
class Practice_Class
{
public:
Practice_Class()
{
  a = 6;
  b = 89;
  c = 45;
}
  void variables_in_class()
  {
    cout << a << " "<< b << " "<< c << " "<< endl;
  }

private:
    int a, b, c;

};


int main()
{
 Practice_Class the_value;
 cout << the_value.variables_in_class();

}
```

Comment: This compiles?  It does not compile for me.  You have typos and invalid syntax.

Comment: If I fix all the compile errors, it works as I would expect.

Comment: remove the `cout <<` around your `variables_in_class()` call, the function does not return anything that could be passed to cout this way

Comment: So what is wrong with the code you show now?  It works [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2cd7fd5e812a04ee)

Comment: Here your program compiles only if  I replace `cout << the_value.variables_in_class();` with `the_value.variables_in_class();` and then it also works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a class that contains a default constructor that is supposed
>   initialize several private member variables.

You do not initialise yours. You *assign* them. Here is the correct way to do it, using an initialisation list:

```
Practice_Class() :
  a(6),
  b(89),
  c(45)
{
}
```

> I am wondering if my variables are ever initialized because when I call the variables_in_class method nothing is printed.

The code should not even compile. See below:

> ```
> cout << the_value.variables_in_class();
> ```

`variables_in_class()` is a `void` function (and a very poorly named one at that). It does not return anything. The fact that it uses streams *internally* is irrelevant at the call site. You cannot pass a non-existing function result to `std::cout`. Just call the function:

```
the_value.variables_in_class();
```

Nevertheless, the idiomatic C++ way is to provide a corresponding output-stream overload for your class, so that you can pass an instance of the class to `std::cout` or other output streams.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Practice_Class
{
public:
    Practice_Class() :
        a(6),
        b(89),
        c(45)
    {
    }

private:
    // so that the function below can access the variables:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Practice_Class const& obj);

    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Practice_Class const& obj)
{
    os << obj.a << " " << obj.b << " " << obj.c;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    Practice_Class the_value;
    std::cout << the_value << '\n';
}
```

Comment: In this simple case assigning or initializing does exactly the same thing. The OP's code compiles and works fine here if I remove the `cout <<` before `the_value.variables_in_class();`

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Of course it doesn't make a difference in this case. I am just trying to teach good habits.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
int main()
{
    Practice_Class the_value;

    // you are outputing in variables_in_class(), not its return values
    the_value.variables_in_class();
}
```

And for your question:

*Will a default constructor with no parameters always intialize variables?*

> No. If you do nothing in default constructor, it will auto call class members' default constructor. Besides that, it does nothing.